# React-bootstrap form checkbox clipping into text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a form using the react-bootstrap Form component, and want a checkbox as one of the fields, but it looks like this:

[image: checkbox clipping into text]

The code that leads to this is really straightforward:

```html
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
     <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="I agree to the terms and conditions" />
  </Form.Group>
```

I'm sure I could fix it with some css hack, but it shouldn't be doing this. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: another css file was setting `margin: 0 auto !important;` on all input elements (a good example of why `!important` is dangerous).

Bootstrap tried to set the checkbox margin to shift it left, but that css was overridden by the other file. I changed the offending css to use a class selector instead, and it works now!

[image]

To anyone having a similar issue, the way I figured this out was that I:

1. Examined the css for the checkbox in developer tools
2. Saw that some fields (namely `margin`) were crossed out
3. Filtered for all instances of `margin`
4. Noted the css file that those instances came from